# react-native : clicking a button to show an online image

Tags: reactjs, button, react-native

I am new to react native and I want to proceed a simple action, i want to click a button to show me an online image from an uri or anything. Any ideas? I know how to use a button, earlier I clicked on it to make an alert basically like this as an action.js:

`export const doAlert = () => {
    alert("ATTENTION!!!");
    return {type: actionTypes.DO_ALERT}
}`

and in my test.js i did like this

```
<Button       
onPress={this.props.doAlert} 
title= "Click to alert"
 />
```

also in the reducer.js it was like this :

```
const DEFAULT_STATE = {onTest:true} export default function (state = DEFAULT_STATE, action) {
switch (action.type){
    case actionTypes.DO_ALERT:
            return {...state, doAlert: true}
            }
```

however, when I try this to show an image it doesnt work,
action.js:

```
export const showImage = () => {
return (dispatch,getState) =>{
    Actions.toSource()
    return {type: actionTypes.SHOW_IMAGE}
}
```

}

any help is appretiated, 
kind regards..

test.js:

```
<Button title="click me"
   onPress= {this.props.showImage}
/>
```

reducer.js :

```
case actionTypes.SHOW_IMAGE:
        source={uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}
        state.source
            return {...state, source : true}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you're actually rendering the image. The Alert works because you don't need anything inside your render to see it. A simple way to make an image appear onPress is by changing the opacity of the image from 0 to 1.

Something like this:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Button, Image } from 'react-native'; 

    export default class ImageTest extends Component {

        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                imgOpacity: 0
            }
        }

        toggleImage() {
            if ( this.state.imgOpacity === 1 ) {
                this.setState({
                    imgOpacity: 0
                })    
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    imgOpacity: 1
                }) 
            }
        }

        render() {
            return(
                <Image
                    style={{width: 50, height: 50, opacity: this.state.imgOpacity}}
                    source={{uri:'https://some-url'}}
                />
                <Button title="click me"
                    onPress= {this.toggleImage}
                /> 
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for answer but this is not what i am asking for. You are just changing the opacity but what i need is first to click button and then observe the image

Comment: A change needs to happens inside the render if you wish to observe the image. You won't be able to view the image anywhere if you're not using an `Image` component. You're grabbing the uri of the image from the reducer but now, you need to put that into an `Image` component. The reducer can also be used to get all the styling you need to "observe" the image how you'd like. Again, an `Alert` doesn't require a specific component inside the render to work but an Image definitely does.